# Import CSV to Django, save data and show results within template

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I need your help with uploading data(CSV) to django app and save data to database. Also i want to show row wise results within the template. Attached is the page image for your reference. Please guide how can i implement the same.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3HTG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I had worked in some similar project similar,  recive a csv and upload the data in different databases.
I used pandas to deal with different types of user friendly tabular extensions, but if you gonna work only with csv you can use the csv lib from python.
you can simply put some form for upload the csv to allow the user to send the file to django application.

these example we used this to catch a xlsx file and then transform in a dataframe(using pandas) to be easy to deal.

```
archiveXLSX = request.FILES['xlsx_file']
df = pd.read_excel(archiveXLSX,keep_default_na=False)
```

now you have the data inside the django backends and need transform these data and make shure who these data are Ok to load in the database.

after all verification we put the data in a list(without save this).

```
list_example = [
   ExampleModel(data1,data2,data3),
   ExampleModel(data1,data2,data3),
]
```

To upload to database, is interesting insert the data using bulk_create(to avoid execute multiples inserts) bulk_create can do it more fast than create one per one .

Ex:

```
ExampleModel.objects.using('database').bulk_create(list_example)
```

so if you want show these data in a template i recommend you to create some table in the database who will indicate the date of upload, file that user uploaded and the id of the data upload from these file. ex:

```
id, file_name ,      date    , id_data
1 ,example.csv,20 - 04 - 2020, 2
2 ,example.csv,20 - 04 - 2020, 4
3 ,example.csv,20 - 04 - 2020, 2
```

Now. To deal whit these two models you need to create the csv model objects while create the model objects for the data from csv (make sure you will save first the model of the Data from csv in these case is ExampleModel).

Let's suppose who after verify these data, processing and these common things. You put them in some dictionary, the function to save them can be like this:

```
csvDataToCreate = []
dataToCreate = []
for data in dataDict:
    example = ExampleModel(data['data1'],data['data2'],data['data3'])
    dataToCreate.append(example)
    csvData = ExampleCsvModel(filename, datetime.now().date(), example)
    csvDataToCreate.append(csvData)
```

now you have all the information you need.
The view for csvData can be a simple select.

```
csvData.objects.filter(file_name='file.csv',date='xx-xx-xxxx')
```

and the template is simple too:

```
  <table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col" style="width: 35%;">data1</th>
    <th scope="col" style="width: 45%;">data2</th>
    <th scope="col" style="width: 5%;">data3</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  {% for csv in csvitens %}
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 35%;"><div class='btn'>{{csv.id_data.data1}}</div></td>
      <td style="width: 35%;"><div class='btn'>{{csv.id_data.data2}}</div></td>
      <td style="width: 35%;"><div class='btn'>{{csv.id_data.data3}}</div></td>
    <tr>
  {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

for this task you can use the css framework of your choice, here i ised boostrap4 .